# How to profiling django tests

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

In my django (very very ancient 1.9) project tests are very slow - `Ran 758 tests in 1017.001s`, ~ 1.3 s/test

How to profile its using Pycharm? Or another IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm already shows the time taken (in ms) next to each test.

If you want more profiling, you can use the method documented by jetbrains for your chosen IDE (pycharm) at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/profiler.html:

- Configure the django integration (Languages & Frameworks -> Django)
- Optionally install the `yappi` profiler in your environment
- Run your tests

  - You can click the green arrow next to the test case
  - You can open a test file, and invoke the "Run" command and select it in the list
  - You can create a profile manually
- Select "Run" -> "Profile {last-thing-you-ran}"